# Missing row in SQL request where count is 0 grouped by the value range

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have o problem with some missing rows on my SQL request. I want to display the amount of occurrences grouped by values and the table needs to display them even when they are no values on the interval.

Here is what it shows now

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Category       |       Amount     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        <= 0         |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       ]0 - 1]       |        18        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         > 2         |        25        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And here is what I need it to show

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Category       |       Amount     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        <= 0         |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       ]0 - 1]       |        18        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       ]1 - 2]       |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         > 2         |        25        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

My code so far is:

```
SELECT  t.range AS Category,
      Count( * )  AS [Amount],
      FROM (
           SELECT value,
                  CASE 
                     WHEN (value <= 0) THEN ' <= 0 ' 
                     WHEN (value > 0 AND value <= 1) THEN ' ]0 - 1]' 
                     WHEN (value > 1 AND value <= 2) THEN ' ]1 - 2]' 
                     WHEN (value > 2 ) THEN ' > 2 ' 
                  END AS range
            FROM Table
       )
       t
GROUP BY t.range;
```

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Thank you already!

Answer (score 2):

Just do multiple query then Union them all:

```
SELECT ' <= 0 ' AS category, count(*) as Amount FROM MyTable WHERE value <= 0
UNION ALL
SELECT ' ]0 - 1]' AS category, count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE value > 0 AND value <= 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ' ]1 - 2]' AS category, count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE value > 1 AND value <= 2
UNION ALL
SELECT ' > 2 ' AS category, count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE value > 1 AND value > 2
```

Comment: Although not the most efficient solution, this is probably the simplest for this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk options here.

**1st option: handle it in application logic?**

I think I would prefer thisone, but it of course depends on what you need to do with it.

**2nd option: use columns instead of rows**

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN (value <= 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ' <= 0 '
    , SUM(CASE WHEN (value > 0 AND value <= 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ' ]0 - 1]'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN (value > 1 AND value <= 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ' ]1 - 2]' 
    , SUM(CASE WHEN (value > 2 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ' > 2 '
FROM Table
```

**3th option: Hardcode options in separate subquery** (the one you initially wanted)

```
SELECT pos.r, COUNT(1) Amount
FROM (
        SELECT ' <= 0 ' r 
        UNION SELECT ' ]0 - 1]' r 
        UNION SELECT ' ]1 - 2]' r 
        UNION SELECT ' > 2 ' r
    ) pos 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
       SELECT value,
              CASE 
                 WHEN (value <= 0) THEN ' <= 0 ' 
                 WHEN (value > 0 AND value <= 1) THEN ' ]0 - 1]' 
                 WHEN (value > 1 AND value <= 2) THEN ' ]1 - 2]' 
                 WHEN (value > 2 ) THEN ' > 2 ' 
              END AS range
        FROM Table
    ) actual ON pos.r = actual.range
GROUP BY pos.r
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always defining the categories, so I have the feeling that it should be a `table`:

> categories(id, range)

and `insert` your ranges into this `table`. When you are done with this, the solution will be as simple as `select`ing `from` `categories` `left join` with the other `table`, on the condition that the `value` meets the `range` you have specified. For those groups which have no values, the result will be `null` for the `count`, so you will need to use `ifnull` to make sure it is 0 if there is no record in the group.

I am not well versed in SqLite, but in other RDBMSes you can add a `varchar` to a query, here that `varchar` would be the evaluation of the `range` you have stored in each category, but if that's not an option in SqLite, then you can write a `stored function` which will do the comparison based on possible `range` values. It should not be very difficult either, but if you can evaluate the `range` string inline somehow, it should be preferred (but only if the possibility of any injection to the ranges is excluded, but that's a different topic).

Answer (score 0):

```
    select
CASE
                     WHEN (startRange <= 0) THEN ' <= 0 '
                     WHEN (startRange > 0 AND startRange <= 1) THEN ' ]0 - 1]'
                     WHEN (startRange > 1 AND startRange <= 2) THEN ' ]1 - 2]'
                     WHEN (startRange > 2 ) THEN ' > 2 '
                  END AS 'range',

  count(m.val) TotalCount
from test m right outer join(
select -100 startRange,0 endrange union all
select 0 startRange, 1 endrange union all
select 1 startRange, 2 endrange union all
select 2 startRange, 3 endrange union all
select 3 startRange, 4 endrange
)r
on m.val >=startrange
  and m.val < endrange
group by r.startRange, r.endRange;
```

Creating a temperory table for range and a right outer join can solve the problem.
Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15276614/5196927